# In Jmeter, http request executed from Command line fails, but passes in GUI mode

Tags: command-line, jmeter

I have multiple http requests under a Thread group, that was always passing till yesterday when executed from either GUI and Command line mode on my Mac system.

Now, when executing from NON GUI mode(Command line), one URL (launching the home page) always **fails when executing on Slave systems from the Master system**

But works when executed on the Master system itself.

I was trying some changes in jmeter.properties. Not sure, if it is anything to do with the error I face now.

My Command line instruction is as below

```
sh Jmeter.sh -n -t R3Performance_Fragment.jmx -G ucount=5 -l Results/r1.csv -R 192.168.X.XX,192.168.X.XX
```

Not sure if I am missing something here, please let me know.

Comment: I did try replacing the original jmeter.properties file. But still it fails just for the homepage url.

Comment: Check manually at your worker (slave) machines if you ever have access to system under test. Like, literally: do a "curl -v <your_failing_url>" from them.

Comment: Will check that, Thanks